# kernel panic not syncing : Attempted to kill the idle task. I got this error while plugging Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: virtualization

Error image is clearly specifying the message.

[image]

Comment: I m connecting through OracleVM Virtual Box Manager version 6. Ubuntu is 64 bit

Comment: I entered to the VM Preferences and checked off "Auto Capture Keyboard".

Comment: I had the same error on the real hardware during boot before entering the boot loader, it happened because of the failure of the memory module, and replacing the memory module fixed it.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, I too faced this error! I was using Seed Ubuntu Machines 12.04 and 16.04. My both machines showed this error. I got it resolved by following steps:

1. Change the processor count to 2(if 1).
2. Enable I/O APIC in motherboard settings.

Note: If invalid settings shown below, check and resolve accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Changing the processor count alone to 2 did the trick, thank you.

Comment: It was also changing to two CPUs that fixed it for me. Interestingly, this error showed up after I upgraded to Windows 11, not sure if the update changed this value or what.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to Check if there is any warnings on the vmbox setting, for me i had the same problem but i changed the display settings to the recommended one VMSVGA and changed the number of processors to two so try the first one

0. also make sure you have Virtualization Technology enabled it maybe a cause for the problem
1. change display settings to VMSVGA if did not work
2. change number of processors to two

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the Hyper-V Solved my issue. Hope it solves yours too.